# Get form field class in template

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, field

I want to check in my template if any of my form fields have certain values in their class.

EG:

*My form field:

```
alcohol_percentage = DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, required=False, label='Alcohol', widget=(NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control percentage'})))
```

*And then in my template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
    {% if 'percentage' in field.widget %}
    <!-- doing something -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like a XY-problem, i.e. you're trying to solve a problem the wrong way. Can you explain what you're really trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to display some text beside the field if its class has X value

Comment: That's not the right way to do things. It's not possible this way. If all you want is display '%', then you can do that in CSS (your input field already has the class "percentage", that's what CSS is for). Again, explain what exactly you're trying to do, what various types of fields you have that require extra stuff to be displayed, etc... If you form only has a couple of fields, you can also just render them explicitly without the for-loop and add specific markup for each field directly knowing the field.